# Google API Console - Reuse deleted project ID

Tags: firebase, google-drive-api, google-api-console

I have accidentally deleted my project at Google API Console and when I try to recreate it, It doesn't give me it's previous ID and attaches unwanted numbers at the end of it.
Is there any way to get that ID back?

Answer (score 2):

If you have deleted a project on [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com). You will get an email from Google something like this.

> Dear Google Developers Console User,
>
> You deleted the project “BigQuery” on Jul 16, 2015 6:33:44 AM PDT. If
>   you still want to delete this project, you don’t need to do anything.
>   The Google Developers Console team will remove your project
>   permanently one week from the time of your request.
>
> If this project shouldn’t be deleted, you must visit the following URL
>   before Jul 28, 2015 12:50:21 PM PDT.
>
> https://console.developers.google.com/project?pendingDeletion=true
>
> After Jul 28, 2015 12:50:21 PM PDT, the project will be inaccessible
>   and can no longer be undeleted.
>
> If you have any questions, please visit the Google Developers Console
>   Help at the following URL, or contact support.
>
> https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/
>
> Thanks, The Google Developers Console Team

If you ignore that email and allow the time to run out.  Your project is gone and I have never known anyone to be able to get it back after that date.   Check your email if you are lucky the date hasn't expired.   If not your project is gone and you need to create a new one with a new project id and accept the consequences of deletion.

IMO: I really wish they would add a lock to projects so we can prevent ourselves from deleting something we really really should not.

Comment: I restore my project and also restore all cloud firebase data. Now everything is okay or I need to follow any other step?

Answer (score 0):

Google project id is system generated and once the project is already deleted, you can't have the same id as before. I suggest you to check if the project is already "shutdown", because I believe that there's a 7 day grace period to recover it. Check out this [google help documentation](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787?hl=en).